# Are there any stone elephants in Shanghai?

Tags: locate-this, shanghai

My boyfriend and I are going to Shanghai.  I wanted to go visit the [Ming Xiaoling Mausoleum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_Xiaoling_Mausoleum) which has these [beautiful stone elephants lining the pathway](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fishywang/5059779224/).  I found out recently that this place is 3 hours from where we are staying and we don't have much time in Shanghai.  Are there any stone elephants similar to this in Shanghai?

Answer (score 5):

As I have lived in Shanghai for 9 years, I don't remember there are any noticeable stone elephants in the city, and if there is, it'd be difficult to find. Unlike some other tourism cities, places in Shanghai are generally small and they scatter around the city, except several places such as the Bund area and some big parks. There're more than 600 "historical architectures" and more than 200 "historical protection places", but as said above, they scatter around the city, and many of them are not open.

I have a personal website where I have a map of all those places marked on Google Maps, but I don't know whether it's ok to put it here so I'll just don't. Let me know if you need it, although I guess you probably don't because your time is limited here.

Here is the link to the map in case people are interested:

http://www.golddc.com/map.html

It's... half Chinese and half English. I don't know why it's so because I only searched in one language when I was making this map. I haven't tried to localize it yet, but some day I will.

**One very important note** to these "historical architectures" is, a lot of them are just some buildings - they are just old and well protected, and in this case they may not arouse any interest. Also mentioned above, many are not open to public. Anyway, my ambition is to physically visit ALL of them, even if at some private places what I can do is to stand outside and peek in. Since they scatter all around the city, I have to carefully design the route to visit them - this is why I have this map.

Most of the points on the map are just addresses. The names of the architectures / buildings are not displayed by Google Maps. Several points are not precise due to the inaccuracy of those addresses (which does happen in Shanghai), but luckily there aren't many such cases.

For a complete list, search for 上海市历史优秀建筑 in Wikipedia.

Comment: Feel free to include your website, as long as you're clear about the fact it's yours - if it's relevant, that's great! :)

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, difficult to find.

[Elephant Trunk Hill Park](http://www.chinaodysseytours.com/guilin/guilin-elephant-trunk-hill.html) has some stone elephant statues in the river, but unfortunately that's [19 hours from Shanghai](http://maps.google.co.nz/maps?saddr=Shanghai,%20China&daddr=%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E5%B9%BF%E8%A5%BF%E5%A3%AE%E6%97%8F%E8%87%AA%E6%B2%BB%E5%8C%BA%E6%A1%82%E6%9E%97%E5%B8%82%E8%B1%A1%E5%B1%B1%E5%8C%BA%E5%8D%97%E6%96%B0%E4%BA%8C%E8%B7%AF%E5%8D%97%E6%96%B0%E8%B7%AF102%E5%8F%B7%20%E8%B1%A1%E5%B1%B1%E5%A4%A7%E9%85%92%E5%BA%97&hl=en&ie=UTF8&sll=31.230393,121.473704&sspn=1.88585,3.56781&geocode=FbmJ3AEdqIo9BykzPPWxQHCyNTGhZMMjlBKVAg;FbF9gQEd0smSBiECiVXgP1pEqw&vpsrc=0&mra=ls&t=m&z=7), so even further away.  Unless you're travelling further into China.

There are some at the [Ming Tombs](http://www.anniebees.com/China/China_19.htm).  I'm not sure if this is the same place as the Ming Xialing Mausoleum, but it's 30 miles from Beijing.

I found [this about the Ming Xialing Mausoleum](http://happybuddha7344.wordpress.com/2010/05/17/nanjing-part-a-april-29/) - the elephants there DO look cool!

But in general, the Mausoleum and Elephant Trunk Hill appear to be the two well-known places that DO have Stone Elephants.